# Xamarin iOS UITextField padding with Border Style None

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to add padding to UITextField. I did some research and found the following code.

```
UIView paddingView = new UIView(new RectangleF(0, 0, 5, 20));
txtBoxUsername.LeftView = paddingView;
txtBoxUsername.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
```

This code works fine till there is a border for UITextField. My UiTextField does not have border. As soon as I set Border None this padding effect is also lost. I am setting border none with following code.

```
txtBoxUsername.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
```

Can anybody please tell me how to add padding to UITextField with no borders.

Comment: your code working perfectly for me,why not working for you

Comment: with or without border ? and in which event did you put my code in ?

Comment: in IB i kept border, and i added your code in ViewDIdLoad, it's working fine. UITextField has no border and even padding also worked

Comment: With border it works.. but as soon as I set border to be none, then it does not work. My main problem statement is to show only bottom border of text box for which I am using rectangle subview, but since as soon as I border padding is also removed and textbox does not look good

Comment: or just try this,not sure ....change your padding view dimensions like          (10, 0, 5, 20)

Comment: no it didnt worked :(

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7039/set-padding-in-uitextfield

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me

```
public class TextBox : UITextField
{
    public TextBox(string placeholder, UIFont font = null)
    {
        Layer.BorderWidth = 0f;
        AttributedPlaceholder = new NSAttributedString(
                            placeholder,
                            font: UIFont.ItalicSystemFontOfSize(15.0f)
                            );
        if (font != null)
        {
            Font = font;
        }
        UIView paddingView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 10.0f, 20.0f));
        LeftView = paddingView;
        LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
    }


}
```